# What is the probability we picked a fake coin if we have 7 proper and 1 with heads on both sides if after we flipped it 7 times we got heads always

Tags: probability

So, I'm going to reformulate the problem because I think I did a bad job in the title because of the word limit:
We have 8 coins in a box - 1 has "heads" on both sides and the remaining 7 are normal. We pick 1 coin randomly and toss it 7 times. If we got "heads" all 7 times, what is the probability the coin is normal.
I have two "solutions" which I think I should combine but I'm not sure how.
1)The probability of picking a normal coin is $7/8$

2)The probability of getting "heads" on a normal coin 7 times in a row is $1/2^7$

Is it the case that both of these events need to occur so I am supposed to multiply the two probabilities and get a $7/2^{10}$ chance?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with Bayes' Theorem.

The probability of having picked a fake coin $\displaystyle P(f) = \frac 18$. The probability of having picked a real coin $\displaystyle P(r) = \frac 78$.

In the event you had picked a fake coin, the probability of your observation ($\displaystyle o$) would be $P\displaystyle (o|f) = 1$.

In the event you had picked a real coin, the probability of your observation would be $P\displaystyle (o|r) = \frac 1{2^7} = \frac 1{128}$.

You want to determine $\displaystyle P(f|o)$.

By Bayes' Theorem,

$\displaystyle P(f|o) = \frac{P(o|f)\cdot P(f)}{P(o|f)\cdot P(f) + P(o|r)\cdot P(r)} = \frac{1\cdot \frac 18}{1\cdot \frac 18 + \frac 1{128}\cdot \frac 78}= \frac{128}{135}$

In other words, it is close to certain your pick was fake.

Comment: Oh, so it was a case of conditional probability, got it. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

$7/2^{10}$ is the prob of getting a fair coin AND flipping heads 7 times.

To get the required conditional probability you need to divide this by the total probability of getting heads 7 times whether the coin is fair or fake.
$$ P(7\text{ heads and fair}) = \frac 7{2^{10}}  $$
$$ P(7\text{ heads and fake }) = \frac 18  $$

$$ P(7\text{ heads}) = \frac 18 +\frac 7{2^{10}}  $$

your answer should be very close to $\frac {56} {2^{10}}$

Comment: I see the fault in my logic now. Thanks!